# How to pass variable from block and access in it twig template

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I'm trying to make custom block but I have problem accessing variables in template.

My block code:

```
namespace Drupal\more_topics_rollout\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
/**
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "more_topics_rollout",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("More topics rollout"),
 *  category = @Translation("Blocks")
 * )
 */
class more_topics_rollout_block extends BlockBase {
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build() {
        return array(
            '#title' => 'More topics'
        );
    }
}
?>
```

My module file:

```
function more_topics_rollout_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array('more_topics_rollout' =>
        array(
            'variables' => array(
                'title' => null,
                'body' => null,
                'description' => null
            ),
            'template' => 'block--more-topics-rollout'
        )
    );
}
```

And when I'm trying to display title with `{{ title }}` it doesn't render. When I'm trying to access variables I know for sure don't exist like `{{ dasdasda }}` it doesn't throw any errors. Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 5):

### Can someone explain this behavior to me?

The render array returned by the build method in the block plugin does not have a theme or type. This means that it will default to markup (iirc). The theme/template is not being used because the render array does not specify to use it.

You can find an example of implementing render arrays on drupal.org's documentation page, [Render arrays](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/arrays). This explains the default element properties.

### How to pass variable from block and access in it twig template?

The render array should have the `#theme` element property set to the theme definition key.

```
  public function build() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'more_topics_rollout',
      '#title' => $this->t('More Topics'),
      '#body' => 'My body',
      '#description' => 'My description'
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why I wasn't able to access my variables from twig. In order to to this your custom block class needs to implement BlockPluginInterface. Maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up solving this issue by adding a param during the preprocess hook - in our case we were modifying the easy_social module to include the current page url

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for easy_social theme.
 *
 * @see easy_social_theme()
 * @see theme_easy_social()
 */
function easy_social_preprocess_easy_social(&$variables) {

  // ...

  $variables['path'] =  Url::fromRoute('<current>',array(),array('absolute'=>'true'));

  // ...
}
```

And then in our Twig file:

```
<p>Your current page is {{ path }}</p>
```